# dependency classes not loaded in executable jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, module, executable-jar

[image: spring modules]

I'm trying to create Several Spring boot applications and merge those and create a one FAT jar (then I can deploy those as separate jars and also can create one jar [micro services and monolithic])

refer :  https://medium.com/@eranda/combine-multiple-springboot-applications-into-a-single-application-649514e7a447

It's working fine on eclipse IDE but does not work when I build and run Jar.

1. parent class

```java
    package com.examp.dcms;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

    @SpringBootApplication
    //@ComponentScan(basePackages ={"com.examp.dcms.customer","com.examp.dcms.audit"})
    public class ApiApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

2. POM xml of parent project(ApiApplication pom)

   ```
   <<dependency>>
       <groupId>com.epic</groupId>
       <artifactId>dcms-audit-service</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.epic</groupId>
       <artifactId>dcms-customer-service</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

I have 3 rest endpoints one inside API application and each in Customer and Audit,

when I'm running on IDE I can get response from all the endpoints, but when I'm building jar and executing only ApiApplication endpoint is working other two are not working(404) , they are not even being constructed when I'm running as a jar, tried to add componetScan on the parent application didn't work.

Comment: can you paste the error log

Comment: @ChiranK. No errors buddy , I have name printing postConstruct methods on each controller seems Audit and Customer (Controller classes which being loaded as dependencies) not being loaded

Comment: Why is the large image relevant for your question?

Comment: just illustrating what I'm trying to do , spring boot modules which can be plunging

Comment: OK, but I think your question would be fine (and better) without it.